# Convert a pandas dataframe to geoTIFF (python)

Tags: pandas, gis, geospatial, arcgis, geopandas

I have a pandas df with X/Y and lat/lon coordinates.

[image]

I want to convert the data frame using lat/lon columns and store the TIFF image in WGS84 CRS.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, you want to store the data in the DataFrame as a TIFF image? It is not immediately obvious what you're expecting.

Answer (score 3):

A couple package recommendations for you: [`xarray`](https://xarray.pydata.org/) and [`rioxarray`](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray).

xarray is pydata's solution to labeled N-dimensional arrays (think pandas but in 3+ dimensions, or think numpy ND-arrays but with pandas indices rather than just positional indices).

rioxarray is an extension package combining xarray with rasterio, giving the ability to read and write raster files including GeoTIFFs. rioxarray has docs on [converting xarray DataArrays to rasters](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/convert_to_raster.html). See also the API docs for converting [`RasterArray`](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_array.RasterArray.to_raster) and [`RasterDataset`](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.raster_dataset.RasterDataset.to_raster) objects to rasters.

In your case, assuming your orthogonal dimensions are `(lat, lon)` and that `model_lat` and `model_lon` are in fact indexed by both lat and lon (e.g. they're in a 3D projection), and that `res` is the band you'd like to encode, your result would look something like this:

```py
import xarray as xr
import rioxarray

da = df.set_index(['lat', 'lon']).to_xarray()

# promote the data variables model lat/long to 2d coordinates
da = da.set_coords(['model_lat', 'model_long'])

da.res.rio.to_raster(filepath)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for 2D Data. Thank you!

Comment: For my dataset, this converted all of my data to `nan`

Comment: Sounds like something else might be going on. Feel free to ask a new question :)